# How to generate a *shell* buffer in emacs?

Tags: linux, shell, emacs

My lecturer does things without explaining, and i've been trying to figure out what shortcut he used to convert his emacs buffer from notes.md to *shell*, but i can't seem to do it. I've researched, and tried using M-x to do it, but that only allows me to type commands in the lower section of the frame, and doesn't convert my whole emacs window to a terminal.

Are there settings i need to change? Is there another shortcut i'm unaware of?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use (M-x shell) to start a shell within emacs. Note that this won't convert your emacs into a terminal, it is just another buffer, with a process running inside it.

As an alternative, you can start an emacs shell with (M-x eshell), the difference is that this shell is implemented in emacs itself, not running an external program.

You can also use (M-x term) to start terminal emulation. Note, however, that inside a terminal emulation buffer you cannot use some of the shortcuts (most are remapped to start with C-c instead of C-x).

If you want a shortcut for starting a shell, you can setup one in your .emacs file:

```
(global-set-key [f10] 'shell) ; pressing F10 starts a shell
```

Also, if your problem is that the shell buffer is only one half of the frame, you can expand it by pressing (C-x 1), that deletes all other windows. Look at [this guide](https://www.iit.bme.hu/~salvi/archive/texts/emacs.txt) I've written some years ago, maybe it will help.

Comment: wow!! so simple....so all i had to do different was type shell after the M-x.....u have no idea how many times i restarted emacs, and tried a million ways.....thanks so much :) :)

Comment: Here's an unsolicited suggestion, though you might have already tried it: *Stop your instructor, and ask your question.* Don't be afraid to ask. Best lesson I ever learned in school, from my 8th-grade math teacher: *Don't ever accept anything on guzzle.* Ask for an explanation, or even a proof. If you are afraid that you might be the only student who doesn't understand, check with the student next to you. You'll likely learn that you are not alone. But even if you are alone, ask for an explanation. If you don't understand something, at least some of the problem is with the explainer.